# How to animate an image slide in left and keep it rotating slowly in Elementor?

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

I would like to combine on an image the animation entrance effect "Slide in Left" in Elementor with a rotation that keeps rotating slowly on the page. When I set up the Slide in Left entrance animation in Elementor it works well, but then when I add some custom code to make it rotate indefinitely it breaks the Elementor animation.

This is the custom CSS I added:

```
.rotate {
  animation: rotation 5s infinite linear;
}
@keyframes rotation {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Animating an image slide to move left and rotating slowly in Elementor can be achieved through a combination of CSS and possibly JavaScript, depending on the complexity of the animation. Here's a general guide to help you implement this effect:

1. Create a Section and Column:

In Elementor, create a new section and add a single-column structure.

2.Add an Image Widget:

Inside the column, add an Image widget and upload the image you want to animate.

3.Custom CSS for Animation:

Go to the Advanced tab of the Image widget, and add a custom CSS class to the image widget (e.g., "animated-image").

Navigate to your WordPress dashboard and go to "Customizer" > "Additional CSS" or use a dedicated custom CSS plugin.

Add the following CSS code to your custom CSS:

```
.animated-image {
    animation: slideAndRotate 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes slideAndRotate {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0) rotate(0deg);
    }
    25% {
        transform: translateX(-25%) rotate(90deg);
    }
    50% {
        transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(180deg);
    }
    75% {
        transform: translateX(-75%) rotate(270deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

Adjust the values in the keyframes to control the speed and rotation angle of the animation.

1.Review and Adjust:

Save the changes and preview your page to see the animated image slide and rotate.

This CSS code utilizes keyframes to create a continuous animation. The translateX property moves the image horizontally (left in this case), and the rotate property adds a rotating effect. The animation is set to run infinitely (infinite) over a duration of 10 seconds (10s).

Feel free to customize the CSS according to your specific design and animation preferences. If you need more advanced or dynamic animations, you might need to consider incorporating additional JavaScript or jQuery code, but for a basic sliding and rotating effect, the provided CSS should work.

Comment: Thank you this is a good start for me! How can I stop the translation when it reaches 100% but keep the rotation to infinite?